# Android - Cannot receive data from PHP

Tags: php, android, http, text, echo

I use `OkHttp` to receive text from a `URL`. The url is a `php` script.

`PHP`:

```
<?php
    echo 'success';
?>
```

I get do this by the following code:

```
OkHttpClient hc = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
String url = "http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php";
HttpUrl.Builder httpUrlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
httpUrlBuilder.addQueryParameter("i", "3");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(httpUrlBuilder.build())
    .build();
Response response = null;
try {
    response = hc.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (response != null) {
    result = response.body().string();
}
```

With a browser, I receive the "success", but in my Android app, I received a garbage (PLEASE READ COMPLETELY):

[image]

It gives a link (URL) which ends with: `?i=1`, so I added this parameter with okhttp: `httpUrlBuilder.addQueryParameter("i", "1");`

After this, I received another garbage and that link ends with: `?i=2`, I tried that, but the server sent another garbage! A link which ends with `?i=3`. When tried this, I received `?i=4` and... (The `i` goes up each time it sends a request)

What is wrong? Why can't I receive that success message?

Comment: Might the i stand for iteration? A parameter for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you explain more, please?

Comment: It's just a guess. But it might be the definition of an iteration. So each time you recieve the link the value has gone up by 1 counting the use of this functionality. So you would have another reference for the testing time/exact request etc. Does the value go up by 1 each time you call the functionality?

Comment: Please post your php script along with the relevant java/kotlin code of your app, without that we cannot help you!

Comment: @Martin, Yes the `i` goes up each time I request URL.

Comment: BTW it appear the script in question is hosted with `www.vcn.ir`, a free webhost. A free webhost appending javascript to website hosted in their environment is not new. BTW their main site also appends `?i={int}` to the url randomly

Comment: [http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php](http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php) visiting this url directly responds `yes` without any *garbage* code

Comment: I can't receive yes or success from this url with my Android app. I need some code to receive that. (All the browsers shows yes, but when use `OkHttp` or `HttpUrlConnection`, it receives that long message instead of yes or success.

Comment: Is there a way for using android WebBrowser and receiving that message from the browser (indirectly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it solved!
I used Android `WebView` and `CookieManager` to get the `text/html` sent by `PHP`.
Steps: 
1. Set a `onPageFinished` on `WebView` (the `WebView` is not VISUAL).
2. Load your URL by `WebView`.
3. When the `onPageFinished` invoked, use `CookieManager` to get the cookie of that URL.
4. Add that cookie to request headers.

```
WebView myWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        final String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php?req=hasimg");                                                                                           
        try {
            myWebView.destroy();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String result = "";
                try {
                    OkHttpClient hc = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .build();
                    String url = "http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php";
                    HttpUrl.Builder httpUrlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
                    httpUrlBuilder.addQueryParameter("req", "hasimg");
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(httpUrlBuilder.build())
                            .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36")
                            .addHeader("Cookie", cookies + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/")
                            .build();
                    Response response = null;
                    try {
                        response = hc.newCall(request).execute();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                        result = response.body().string();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // WE RECEIVED THE TEXT IN HTML (mine is 'yes')
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}).start();
    }
}
myWebView.loadUrl("http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php?req=hasimg");
```

Notes:

**1. This receives the HTML body text, not plain text.**

**2. This method passes the [testcookie-nginx-module](https://kyprizel.github.io/testcookie-nginx-module/), a human check system. We use real cookies to do that.**

**3. You should add query params to the URL which you load with `WebView` (add `?key=value`), but you shouldn't add this to the URL which you load with `OkHttp` (add with `httpUrlBuilder.addQueryParameter("key", "value")`).**

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `text/html`, the default with PHP. Obviously the browser renders the stuff you're supposed to see, but indeed the response the browser received had the full HTML.

Maybe send JSON instead?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['message' => 'success']);
exit;
```

> UPDATE Ok, you now send JSON, but remarkably still get all that garbage!

Try this for your Android code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url('http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php')
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Comment: How to receive the JSON from Android?

Comment: Good question! I don't know! Try sending it and see what happens! Log or display the response!

Comment: Look here for parsing your JSON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android#9606629

Comment: Not worked, returned that garbage :(  It works on browser: http://hadifaridhadi.vcn.ir/com.hfapp.rokatshomar/imgofday.php

Comment: You didn't put the content type header, I see in the response headers `Content-Type  text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: I did, this is the new php: `<?php
    header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    echo json_encode(['message' => 'success']);
?>`

Comment: Nope, it's definitely html you are sending, look at my inspector https://pasteboard.co/HKfl5zW.png

Comment: Sorry! My fault! This! `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I fixed that, but I still receive that garbage! With a link which is i+1

Comment: truly bizarre. can you do a site wide search? CTRL-F and look for where that JS is coming from?

Comment: Probably I'm receiving this garbage because of using free hosting. I'll test it on localhost and send you the result.